# How to install Node.js in custom folder silently on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, silent-installer

I create a script to auto install all my dev stack on Windows.

I have a problem with Node.js

What's the command line to install **node-v0.10.23-x64.msi** in **C:\Tools** silently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I found it.

This is the correct way to install Node.js on Windows silently in a custom directory.

```
msiexec.exe /i node-v0.10.23-x64.msi INSTALLDIR="C:\Tools\NodeJS" /quiet
```

Answer (score 8):

```
msiexec.exe /i node-v0.10.23-x64.msi /qn
```

- `/i` means normal install
- `/qn` means no UI

I do not known how to set the destination, you can read documentation here, and check if msi supports it:

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html

Comment: I already tried that but Node.js is not available from cmd (not in the PATH) after installation and I don't find how to specify a destination.

Comment: Can you specify TARGETDIR? Have you close cmd.exe and open it again?

Answer (score 4):

This will do the exact installation as doing it manual from the UI

```
msiexec /i node-v6.11.2-x64.msi TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\nodejs\" ADDLOCAL="NodePerfCtrSupport,NodeEtwSupport,DocumentationShortcuts,EnvironmentPathNode,EnvironmentPathNpmModules,npm,NodeRuntime,EnvironmentPath" /qn
```

Comment: Thanks for getting the 'add to path' option included, I've been scouring for that

Answer (score 3):

To expand a little on foozar's answer, which works.

```
msiexec.exe /i node-v0.10.23-x64.msi INSTALLDIR="C:\Tools\NodeJS" /quiet
```

Note that `/quiet` may be better replaced with `/passive`:

- Passive shows the status bar, and more importantly, prompts the user for the admin password if needed.
- Quiet mode will just fail if the installer doesn't have privileges.